# How to convert outer apply in entity framework core

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a requirement to convert an entire SQL stored procedure to LINQ. there is OUTR Apply section and I need to convert it to LINQ.

for example
-- more joins here

```
  LEFT JOIN Reason ON Reason.ReasonID = jd.ReasonID
             OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT s.SiteNameSimpleAddress
            FROM jobvisit jv
                 INNER JOIN site s ON jv.siteid = s.siteid
                                      AND jd.JobVisitID = jv.jobvisitid
        ) s
```

note that "jd.JobVisitID" exists in another join above, not inside the outer apply. looks like it attended to make the equal for the left join.

please correct my question if there is something wrong I wrote without hard criticize

Answer (score 0):

They the following. Since you have not posted your model I'm trying to show schematically.

```cs
var query = 
   ...
   join reason in ctx.Reasons on jd.ReasonId equals reason.ReasonId
   from address in (from jv in ctx.JobVisit
                    from s in ctx.Site
                      .Where(s => jv.SiteId == s.Siteid && jd.JobVisitID == jv.JobVisitID)
                    select s.SiteNameSimpleAddress).DefaultIfEmpty()
   ...
```

Comment: it is converted to two CROSS APPLY

Comment: It should be. If not, you have problem and can create issue in EF repositry. Forgot about DefaultIfEmpty, updated.

Comment: kindly i need more information. do you mean the outer apply will be converted to two cross apply after i follow the syntax you provided ? 

i wanted to have the same outer apply in SQL profiler after i execute the linq statement

Comment: It should be converted to one OUTER APPLY. I don't think that EF is so good to optimize this query in exact SQL, but our LINQ provider (linq2db) will create almost identical query.